# What if rep gains were weighted by OP's rep on a given topic?

Tags: feature-request, reputation

I don't have the numbers to back it up, but I've getting the feeling that there is an increasing number of newbie questions on SO, paired with an increasing number of more elaborated questions, coming from more experienced users, that go unanswered.

For the record, I know I can only speak from my narrow field of programming tags that I follow, but if this is a reality in other spaces, then the consequence of this situation is that good questions go unanswered because it is easier to answer a greater number of questions made by new users. I can't know for certain that this issue is real, but it is my personal experience. If it's both, then you should consider the following:

So I was thinking: ***what if rep gains from answering a question were weighted by the OP's rep on the tag that he/she used to make their question?*** This is, the more rep in a particular tag from the asker, the more rep points awarder from upvotes and acceptance of answers.

This would nudge people to give an extra effort to answer questions from more experienced users, and you could still be getting points from new user's questions, which are generally easier to answer.

So imagine a question with the [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) tag made by a user who has 1.4k reputation overall, but just 500 points of said reputation coming from [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) related questions and answers. The rep points gained from answering this question would be the same if OP had the same 500 rep points coming from [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) related questions and answers, no matter how high or low is their overall rep.

Maybe this would be hard to implement (maybe there would be a lot of side effects), so... just throwing it out there. What do you think?

Comment: So.... you think that if Jon Skeet creates a new account today, the fact he is Jon Skeet won't show in his questions?

Comment: This sounds like exactly the problem bounties are meant to solve.

Comment: Questions from people who don't typically ask questions tend to be... harder to solve, because they can already solve most of the easy questions people ask on a daily basis on their own. They also tend to be questions that few other people have, and thus end up being less interesting/useful. That's not a sign of the system being broken or in need of change, the system just isn't designed to reward users based on the difficulty of the question. Users are rewarded based on how many other people find it useful, which trends toward easier questions.

Comment: Without knowing which tags are involved in the observations it's difficult to say, but... One factor could be that a number of experts have left the site or reduced their activity in the past months, due to how Stack Overfow (the company) has changed how the site is managed. A tough question won't be answered if there's no one reading it with the knowledge to provide the information.

Comment: “ I don't have the numbers to back it up”, I stopped reading your proposal at this point, because you don’t have the numbers to backup anything you said.

Answer (score 14):

All questions are born equal.

Same with votes.

Votes on an answer on a question by Jon Skeet should weigh the same as any other vote, no matter who was voting on the answer (Skeet himself, or a random user passing by).

And if we really have a problem with "experienced users not getting answers to their questions", we already have a solution for that. These users have more reputation, which they can use to set bounties and drive additional attention to their questions.